# How do I split text into rows and print its corresponding value?

Tags: split

I want to split a text into rows and print its value, for example, change this:

```
YLB; YLR; YLS (tab) 30
```

Into this:

```
YLB (tab) 30
YLR (tab) 30
YLS (tab) 30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="[; \t]+"; OFS="\t"} {for (i=1; i<NF; i++) print $i, $NF}'
```

Ex.

```
$ echo 'YLB; YLR; YLS     30' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[; \t]+"; OFS="\t"} {for (i=1; i<NF; i++) print $i, $NF}'
YLB     30
YLR     30
YLS     30
```

Comment: Perfect!!! Thank you very much steeldriver:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sed 's/; /\n/g' yourfile
```

See this post:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486203/to-insert-line-breaks-in-a-file-whenever-a-comma-is-encountered-shell-scrip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486203/to-insert-line-breaks-in-a-file-whenever-a-comma-is-encountered-shell-script)t

Comment: Thanks for your reply however it doesnt give me what I need. it changes ; into new rows but I need the value "30" in each line too. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you could do it with "sed":

```
TAB=`echo 'x' | tr 'x' '\011'`; # tab
SPC=`echo 'x' | tr 'x' '\040'`; # space
WS="[${SPC}${TAB}]";            # whitespace regex
echo "YLB; YLR; YLS ${TAB} 30" |
sed -ne "
    /\n/!G
    s/^\([^;]*\);${WS}*\(.*\)\(${WS}${TAB}.*\)/\1\3\2\3/
    P;/\n.*\n/D
 "
```

We have to have the shell variables TAB/SPC/WS as the POSIX "sed" does not support \t \s hence this is a poor-man's implementation of those.

Comment: Thanks for that Rakesh. I did try some versions of sed but couldn't find anything that worked.

Comment: Did you get any errors regarding "event G: not found" ?

Comment: No, the way I did it just replaced each ";" with a new line but didnt transfer over the "30".